# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError : companion-bubble.js

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

please let me know if anyone have the solution for this error.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>) at companion-bubble.js`

[image: console error]

i want to remove this error.

Comment: We need to see the relevant part of your code that causes this error, please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Now it's fixed, the error was caused by loom extension installed in Chrome.

Thanks for your valuable time man!

Comment: thanks I was having this error too,I too have the loom extension installed so I think that is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the Loom Chrome Extension installed - it can inject this `companion-bubble.js` error. Disable the extension to avoid the pollution.